# MySQL Database Size Limit Exceeded

Tags: wordpress, post-meta

My hosting company only allows 1GB per database.  There is a table in my database, wpas_postmeta, and it is 3.6 GB. Any suggestions on how I would go about on deleting some of this data without affecting my WordPress website.

Comment: It might be useful if the structure (DDL) of this table is known, otherwise a [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html) might be the only answer.....

Answer (score 1):

Postmeta is the worst offender in all the WP tables for size because of the architecture of Wordpress. Just about every plugin you use probably needs to store info in post meta. Every image you upload in a post goes into post meta. Here is an article for more info and how to query the table for specific data. I know linking to an existing article is kind of taboo for StackOverflow but I found this really helpful:

https://www.webnots.com/large-post-meta-table-in-wordpress-here-is-how-to-cleanup/